# FrameworkElement.Parent and VisualtreeHelper.GetParent behaves differently

Tags: .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, visualtreehelper, frameworkelement

In a WP7 app, I used FrameworkElement.Parent recursively to determine whether a specific element is inside of another element. But it does not always work correctly.
Then I changed my code to use VisualtreeHelper.GetParent method recursively, and it always work correctly(so far as I tested).

So what is the difference of them?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider `ControlA` and `ControlB` where ControlA is a content control meaning it can contain other controls.

```
<ControlA>
   <ControlB />
</ControlA>
```

Logically the Parent property of the ControlB instance is an instance of ControlA in this case.

However if you were to look at `Template` setter of the default style of ControlA you may find complex Xaml containing some visual state management and a hierarchy of Borders and Grids and finally buried in that lot there is a `ContentPresenter` where the child control will be placed.

Recursively looping up VisualTreeHelper.Parent will find each element defined in the template from the `ContentPresenter` up to the "logical" parent element and then beyond.

Comment: meaning that VisualTreeHelper.GetParent returns the visual tree parent and FrameworkElement.Parent returns the logical tree parent?

Answer (score 1):

> "The value reported by the FrameworkElement.Parent property in
> Silverlight is generally the same value that would be reported by
> using VisualTreeHelper API, because the two tree concepts are
> frequently synchronized as far as how parent-child relationships are
> reported. However, there may be cases where FrameworkElement.Parent
> reports a parent that VisualTreeHelper does not."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.parent(v=VS.95).aspx

Comment: I've read the document, but it does not explain when and why they behave differently.

Comment: I see exactly that. VisualTreeHelper.GetParent gives null while FrameworkElement.Parent is not null. This on WinRT though.