# UWP VisualTreeHelper.GetParent() returns null

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a `ContentDialog` which has a `ListView`. This `ListView's` DataTemplate Contains a `Grid` and this `Grid` has a `Button`. The code goes like this:

```
<ContentDialog x:Name="DownloadListDialog" x:FieldModifier="public" Grid.Column="1">
    <ListView Name="AssetsListView" IsItemClickEnabled="False" Grid.Row="1" SelectionMode="Single" MaxHeight="500" ItemsSource="{x:Bind _viewModel.Assets, Mode=OneWay}">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                       ...
                       ...
                    </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewModel:AssetViewModel">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind name}"/>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind lblFileSize}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind contentSize, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind contentUrl}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <Button Content="Download" Click="Button_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentDialog>
```

Here's my Button Click event handler:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var grid = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(sender as Button) as Grid;
    ...
    ...
}
```

The problem is that the variable `VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(sender as Button) as Grid` always returns `null` on my PC. But this same code when I deploy on my mobile works perfectly fine (i.e, variable `grid` gets assigned the correct value).

**UPDATE:** 
Here's my Live Visual Tree and it confirms that the button has a parent grid.
[image]

App min version: build 14393
App target version: Build 15063
PC windows version: Build 17134 (version 1803)

Note: I've tried changing the App target version to 1803 but the problem remains.

Comment: Do you want a workaround or to know why it's null? Workarounds are doable, answers are more difficult

Comment: A proper answer would be great. But i would also like to add that the same code used to work fine a while back.

Comment: Weird - I've tried your code and seems to work fine. Can you check if `var obj = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(sender as Button);` returns anything?

Comment: Use the tools that are available to you. Go to **Debug/Windows/Live Visual Tree** and verify it. [Here's your list view containing 5 items, showing the first item with the button as a child of the grid, as expected](https://imgur.com/4Hicfy6).

Comment: @Romasz that returns null.

Comment: @jsanalytics I've verified it it returns null on pc and correct value on mobile.

Comment: @ravikumar are you saying you verified that the visual tree is the same in both cases, the one that works and the one that doesn't?

Comment: Also please update your question showing the exact context your `ContentDialog` is being called. Your **OS Edition, Version and Build** should be pertinent information as well.

Comment: @jsanalytics I've updated my question.

Comment: I tried to create a sample to test this issue, but after the dialog shows, I clicked the button, I can get its parent Grid. I can not reproduce this issue in my side, it would help us look into this issue in the same point if you can provide a reproducible project. Moreover, I found you have asked this issue in the MSDN, please check the [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/14c7ed67-2902-4515-a2c8-2a4e9bdf3343/uwp-visualtreehelpergetparent-returns-null?forum=wpdevelop).

Answer (score 4):

As I understand from a different question there are several ways to get the parent of the VisualTreeHelper. Could it be that on your mobile or PC for that matter in the background different things are loaded so that the location of where you can find the grid object changes.

You could check this answer as a reference of what I stated above: [FrameworkElement.Parent and VisualtreeHelper.GetParent behaves differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921881/frameworkelement-parent-and-visualtreehelper-getparent-behaves-differently?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Nope. Even the Parent property of `sender as Button` is null.

Comment: I can see many people have problems with getting the right controls from the VisualTreeHelper. I cannot test your problem here but have you tried to use 'LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent()'? Also I found a resource which could give you more insights: http://shrinandvyas.blogspot.com/2013/01/wpf-visualtreehelper-find-parent-of.html